# What is the cleanest way to convert &str types to numeric types?

Tags: type-conversion, rust

I find myself reading large CSV files and collecting the numerical elements into a `Vec<&str>`. Thereafter I have to convert them to numeric types and the simplest way I've found to do that is to implement a function like this:

```
fn to_u32(str: &str) -> u32
{
    let str_num: Option<u32> = str.parse();
    match str_num
    {
        Some(num) => num,
        None      => panic!("Failed to read number"),
     }
 }
```

This seems like a fairly common operation so I've sifted through the reference docs but haven't found anything that matches it. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use the `csv` crate which will do all this type based decoding for you. There are examples in the README and docs. https://github.com/BurntSushi/rust-csv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Option`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/option/enum.Option.html) type has a large variety of adapter methods which can be used to munge the data around more nicely than repeated `match`s.

For example, there's [`unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) and [`expect`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect) for just extracting the data out of a `Some`, panicking if the `Option` is `None`. The `expect` method is actually the closest to your written code: `str.parse().expect("Failed to read number.")`.

---

However, it can often makes sense to use other the functions listed there, to propagate errors, avoiding the hard "crash" of a panic and allowing users (or yourself) to handle errors more centrally and with more control. It also often makes sense to use [`Result`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/result/enum.Result.html) for this, which gives you the chance to pass along more information in the error case, and also allows one to use [the `try!` macro](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/result/index.html#the-try!-macro), that said, one can easily define an equivalent of `try!` for `Option`:

```
macro_rules! option_try {
    ($e: expr) => {
        match $e {
            Some(x) => x,
            None => return None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use [`unwrap()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) to avoid pattern matching, but you should do it sparingly - with `unwrap()` you can't handle the actual parse error, so if the string does not represent a number, it'll panic:

```
let str_num: u32 = str.parse().unwrap();
```

`if let` is also an option:

```
if let Some(str_num) = str.parse::<u32>() {
    // ...
}
```

You can also use [`unwrap_or()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) if you want to specify some default value:

```
let str_num: u32 = str.parse().unwrap_or(42);
```

Or you can use [`unwrap_or_default()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default) which employs [`Default`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) instance for `u32`:

```
let str_num: u32 = str.parse().unwrap_or_default();
```